# Spring @Transactional and PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW with sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, spring, spring-transactions

I have a service that has several methods marked with `@Transactional`, including methods a, b and c. These 3 methods are nested in the following way a -> b -> c. Here is a code sample:

```
@Transactional
public void a() {
    while(condition) {
        try {
            b();
        } catch(MyException e) {
            logger.warn(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Method b however is annotated like this:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW, rollbackFor = {MyException.class})
```

However, when `MyException` is thrown from method c, the exception is caught at method a and when that exits, the transaction is comitted and that includes whatever has been done by call to b() that threw the exception and should have been rolled back(?). 
I am using sql server 2012 express with spring 3.0.7 and my spring configuration is like this:

```
<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <qualifier value="txm1"/>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="classpath:META-INF/jpa-persistence.xml"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="Unit1" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method `b` seems to be in the same class as method `a`. If you're not using AspectJ, the `@Transactional`-annotations are handled by a JDK dynamic proxy, through which your calls from outside the class travel to method `a`. The call needs to travel through the proxy for the `@Transactional`-annotations to have effect, see for example here, under 'Understanding AOP proxies': http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/spring-framework-reference/html/ch08s06.html

> The key thing to understand here is that the client code inside the
>   main(..) of the Main class has a reference to the proxy. This means
>   that method calls on that object reference will be calls on the proxy,
>   and as such the proxy will be able to delegate to all of the
>   interceptors (advice) that are relevant to that particular method
>   call. However, once the call has finally reached the target object,
>   the SimplePojo reference in this case, any method calls that it may
>   make on itself, such as this.bar() or this.foo(), are going to be
>   invoked against the this reference, and not the proxy. This has
>   important implications. It means that self-invocation is not going to
>   result in the advice associated with a method invocation getting a
>   chance to execute.